# Block All Users But One From SSH Access

Tags: linux, ssh

I can currently login to my server via ssh as root.  There may be some other users, however, that have ssh access.  I want to block out any possible logins except from root.  How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you can achieve your stated desire with the AllowUsers directive in your sshd_config file, for example:

```
$ grep AllowUsers /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AllowUsers root
```

However I would be wary of using the root account for ssh - consider instead an unprivileged account for normal use, using something like sudo to acquire root privileges only when needed.

Answer (score 5):

From [man sshd_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config)

```
 AllowUsers
         This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated
         by spaces.  If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match
         one of the patterns.  Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID is
         not recognized.  By default, login is allowed for all users.  If the pat‐
         tern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and HOST are separately checked,
         restricting logins to particular users from particular hosts.  The
         allow/deny directives are processed in the following order: DenyUsers,
         AllowUsers, DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups.

         See PATTERNS in ssh_config(5) for more information on patterns.
```

Btw. please don't allow passwords login for your root user. Only allow ssh keys or even better just allow a specific user to login and change to root but not root directly.

Comment: hey, thx for the answers so far.  Does it matter where in the file I put AllowUsers root?  Also, out of curiosityk, why is logging as as some other users and sudo-ing to root more secure than logging in as root?

Comment: It does not matter. If you just allow ssh keys there should be no problem but there was for example a bug in ssh-keygen in debian which produced guessable ssh-keys. This would allow an easy access to your system just with some simple bruteforce. In general it is always a good idea to do privilege separation and run as less commands as possible with administrative privileges.

Comment: thx mru, i upvoted you but accepted the other answer cause it had the exact line i needed.

Answer (score 0):

I lockout all users except root when I need to do maintenance on my Linux hosts.  Just remove the file when you're done.

```
echo "System maintenance in progress" > /run/nologin
```